# Безопасные массивы (без указателей)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ооп

Имеется следующий код:

```
const int LIMIT = 100;
class safearray
{
    private:
        int start, last;
        int arr[LIMIT];
    public:
        safearray() : start(0), last(100) {}
        safearray(int s, int l) : start(s), last(l) {}
        int& operator[](int n)
        {
            if (last - start > 100 || start > last)
            { cout << "Out of range! Size of your array is " << last - start << endl; exit(1); }
            if (n < start || n >= last)
            { cout << "Wrong index!" << endl; exit(1); }
            return arr[n];
        }
        int getstart()
        { return start; }
        int getlast()
        { return last; }
};

int main()
{
    safearray sa1(100, 175);
    for (int i = sa1.getstart(); i < sa1.getlast(); i++) sa1[i] = i;
    for (int i = sa1.getstart(); i < sa1.getlast(); i++) cout << "Element " << i << " is " << sa1[i] << endl;
}
```

Если запускать с конструктором, как у меня в примере, компилятор сначала выводит все элементы, а потом ругается:

```
Run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'sa1' was corrupt.
```

Не очень понимаю как это исправить

UPD: текст задачи

> Дополните класс safearray из программы ARROVER3 этой главы так, чтобы
> пользователь мог определять и верхнюю, и нижнюю границы массива
> (например, индексы, начинающиеся с 100 и заканчивающиеся 200). Имеем перегруженную операцию доступа к членам массива, проверяющую
> индексы каждый раз, когда к массиву нужен доступ, для проверки того,
> что мы не вышли за пределы массива. Вам понадобится конструктор с
> двумя аргументами, который определяет верхнюю и нижнюю границы.
> Так как мы еще не изучили, как выделять память динамически, то данные
> класса все еще будут размещаться в массиве, состоящем из 100 элементов,
> но вообще вы можете преобразовывать индексы массива safearray в индексы реального массива целых чисел произвольным образом. Например, если пользователь определил диапазон от 100 до 175, то вы можете преобразовать его в диапазон от arr[0] до arr[75].

а также код ARROVER3

```
const int LIMIT = 100;
class safearray
{
 private:
 int arr [ LIMIT ];
 public:
_________________________________________________________________ 333
// обратите внимание, что функция возвращает ссылку!
 int& operator[ ] ( int n )
 {
 if ( n < 0 || n >= LIMIT )
 { cout << "\nОшибочный индекс!"; exit ( 1 ); }
 return arr [ n ];
 }
};

int main ( )
{
 safearray sa1;
 // задаем значения элементов
 for ( int j = 0; j < LIMIT; j++ )
 sa1[ j ] = j * 10; // используем функцию слева от знака =
 // показываем элементы
 for ( j = 0; j < LIMIT; j++ )
 {
 int temp = sa1 [ j ]; // используем функцию справа от знака =
 cout << "Элемент " << j << " равен " << temp << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сразу говорю - не предлагайте делать это с указателями, автор книги хочет, чтобы я сделал это без них

Comment: Надо же, сделано аж две разных проверки на индекс, а потом массив индексируется невалидным значением...

Comment: Ну что же, пытался извернуться, как мог

Comment: Может перед `return arr[n];`стоит добавить еще и третью проверку, что `n` является валидными индексом для `arr`?

Comment: Ну можно конечно return arr[n]; запихнуть в else ко второй проверке, но сути дела это не поменяет

Comment: Просто понимаете, первая проверка существует, чтобы прям сразу откинуть неправильные массивы, а вторая проверяет элемент на валидность

Comment: Нет, вам нужна именно третья отдельная проверка, что `n` является валидными индексом для `arr`, потому что первые две этого не проверяют. Подсказка: значения start, last в такой проверке участия принимать не должны.

Comment: Хорошо, я попробую

Comment: Сделал проверку if (n >= start || n < last) return arr[n]; и она не работает. Может вы имели ввиду другую?

Comment: я же дал подсказку: значения `start`, `last` в такой проверке участия принимать не должны.

Comment: Вы точно понимаете что вы хотите? Во-первых хочу заметить что вы путаетесь в терминах: выполнением программы у вас почему-то занят компилятор, last вместо последнего элемента является размером, start у вас вообще не понятную функцию исполняет... Лучше опишите, что вы хотите сделать, а то исходя из кода это совершенно не очевидно

Comment: Да и что значит "без указателей"?

Comment: Если уж вы работаете с `LIMIT`, то используйте его везде...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch По-моему очевидно, то тут start и last задают диапазон индексов для класса safearray, который может отличаться от диапазона индексов встроенных массивов. Кстати это очень полезная фича и более толковых языках (таких как Ada) доступная из коробки.

Comment: Я добавил текст задачи и исходного класса в тексте вопроса

Comment: @user7860670 по-моему для вас самих это не очевидно, ибо почему у вас start больше размера вашего массива?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Потому что значениями start и last задаются промежутки массива. Ещё раз напомню, что текст задачи я добавил в вопрос

Comment: @АлександрII а я вам ещп раз укажу, что вы обращаетесь за пределы массива! Куда, по-вашему, вы обращаетесь при start==100 и n==0?

Comment: Небольшая опечатка: при n==100, а не 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша самая главная ошибка - возврат

```
return a[n];
```

в то время как надо

```
return a[n - start];
```

И еще - все 100 замените на `LIMIT` - какой вообще иначе смысл в этом значении?

И - какой смысл в двух конструкторах, если легко обойтись одним -

```
safearray(int s = 0, int l = LIMIT) : start(s), last(l) {}
```

Comment: Действительно, подвох был в n - start. Кстати, по поводу конструктора вы подсказали очень удобную вещь, я над таким даже не думал. Спасибо большое :)